# Setting width in ie11/Edge on element - assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ecmascript-5

I am selecting an element that I need to change the size of the element based on certain rules all works fine in major browsers but in ie11/Edge it does not work.

```
this.visContainer = this.$element[0].querySelector('.am-visualization-render-area__vis-container');
```

Here is where it goes wrong I'm trying to set a value to a read-only property

```
 const visContainerBounds = this.visContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
 visContainerBounds.width -= this.marginHorizontal;
 visContainerBounds.height -= this.marginVertical;
```

This returns the error

> assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode

I have also tried

```
this.visContainer.clientWidth -= this.marginHorizontal;
this.visContainer.clientHeight -= this.marginVertical;
const visContainerBounds = this.visContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Now from my findings, this is caused by ie and edge following the ECMAScript5 standard and chrome ff safari aren't in this case.

My question is how can I set the value of the width of the element without this error throwing? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you set the style directly; like:

```
this.visContainer.style.width="100px";
```

Comment: I need to be able to change the width property is this possible?

Comment: This does answer the question so upvoted but i guess my real question should be how can i change the width of the element not the style

Comment: yep.. you can set any valid value